# Dropdown field automatically closes after opening in IE11

Tags: html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I have a dropdown which has some options in it.

```
<div class="control-group pull-left">
    <label class=" help-inline"> Notify staff
       <input type="text" class="span1 min" name="someName"/>
       <select id="duration-unit-outingMinCutoff" name="duration-unit-outingMinCutoff" class="span2">
           <option value="minutes" selected="selected">minutes</option>
           <option value="hours" selected="selected">hour(s)</option>
           <option value="days" selected="selected">day(s)</option>
       </select>
       prior to start time
     </label>
</div>
```

When I click on dropdown it opens and closes suddenly on IE. Open [this](https://jsfiddle.net/tk4hmqyk/4/) in IE and you can see issue i am talking about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your use of `<label>` is the issue.  IE11 doesn't handle labels around controls well. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lfa62bxq/1/).

```
<div class="control-group pull-left">
    <label class=" help-inline"> Notify staff</label>
    <input type="text" class="span1 min" name="group.outingMinCutoff" />
    <select id="duration-unit-outingMinCutoff" name="duration-unit-outingMinCutoff" class="span2">
      <option value="minutes">
        minutes
      </option>
      <option value="hours">
        hour(s)
      </option>
      <option value="days">
        day(s)
      </option>
    </select>
    <label> prior to start time</label>
</div>
```

Comment: But, how is this not an issue with other browsers?

Comment: @HemanthGowda Because they don't use the same rendering engines.

Comment: Thank you so much. You saved me a whole day of IE11 headaches.